# Color tiles in Windows 10 desktop apps

Tags: c#, windows-10, desktop-application, tile, startmenu

I noticed with the first big Windows 10 update that some desktop apps have tiles in a different color than the one I have for accent color, like Firefox, which has a dark-gray tile color:

[image: Firefox]

However, not all apps have this, and use the default accent color, like Blender.

[image: Blender]

I wonder if this change is similar to what Windows 8.1 did with an updated Start screen, in which [you could set the color of a desktop app tile via XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn449733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I'm a novice with the Windows platforms in C#, and I think it would be nice to implement in my programs a more customized tile on the start screen, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a UWP app, you can set the tile background color in the app manifest, e.g.:

```
<uap:VisualElements
  DisplayName="MyApp"
  Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
  Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
  Description="MyApp description"
  BackgroundColor="#ffff00">
  ...
  <uap:SplashScreen
    Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png"
    BackgroundColor="#ff0000" />
</uap:VisualElements>
```

This sets the tile background to yellow, and independently sets the splash screen background to red.

For a desktop app, **[this link is likely more useful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn449733.aspx)**.

Comment: Like I said, this is **not** an Universal Windows app, so I presume it does not have these kind of features.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I updated my answer with a link that seems relevant (I don't have time to test this now, and I don't want to copy/paste untested code).